# Grouping a column classified by KMeans(cluster no=4) by another column in dataframe(Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, grouping, cluster-analysis

First of all, my dataset had singer and lyrics. I wanted to classify the lyrics of these singers in order to group them. So I converted the lyrics to a 768 array using one of the "SentenceTransformer" models. Then I found the ideal cluster number to implement KMeans with both Elbow and Silhouette methods and applied KMeans according to this number. As a result, I got a situation where the lyrics were divided into 4 different groups. I also added this to the dataframe.

Now there is a point where I am stuck. I want to classify the singers according to this class column. But since there will be different class values for a singer, what would be the ideal way to do this?
If I take the mean of the class column by singers, I will have a single class value for each singer. Can I get a successful result if I classify it by dividing it into intervals according to this single value found? Or are there other ways to deal with these situations?

```
            singer       class
0         Barış Manço      0
1         Barış Manço      3
2         Barış Manço      2
3         Barış Manço      1
4         Barış Manço      2
...          ...          ...
4423      Şebnem Ferah     0
4424      Şebnem Ferah     1
4425      Şebnem Ferah     1
4426      Şebnem Ferah     0
4427      Şebnem Ferah     1
```

class[0,1,2,3] => so cluster number is 4

```
In[9]: gk = df.groupby("singer")["class"]
In[11]:gk.head()

Out[11]:

0       0
1       3
2       2
3       1
4       2
       ..
4331    2
4332    0
4333    0
4334    0
4335    0
```

I tried this method but it didn't work.
What could be the reason for the increase in the number of rows here?

Comment: This _could_ be a very good question. [Offer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a small dataset in the question text which SO folks can copy-n-paste so they're working with a portion of your records. Try copying from SO yourself to verify it works. Is your summary goal to pick the majority class, per singer? So we need (singer, class) .count()s, across each singer's songs?

Comment: The model you have trained has clustered _songs_ and not _singers_. If you want to use these to group the artist, then you could combine all of the lyrics for each artist into a single row and then build a new model on that data or you could group by singers and aggregate the mean or mode to determine the class most often assigned to the artist's songs

Comment: Thank you for the comments and recommendations. I tried combining the songs of each artist separately in rows, but the elbow or silhouette method did not produce a very efficient result. The most logical way seems to be to use mode.